# Add a new property to Interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have an API `interface` like below. I cannot add any property to it since it is not under my control.But I need to include boolean property like `isPhotoSelected: boolean = false;` to it. Can you tell me how to do that?

```
export interface LibraryItem {
    id: string;
    photoURL: string;
    thumbnailURL: string;
    fileName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `class` that `implements` the `interface`.

```
export class DtoLibraryItem implements LibraryItem{
    //need to declare all the properties of the interface here
    isPhotoSelected: boolean
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this kind of solution now. But it doesn't allow me to use the same name for the class (i.e. `LibraryItem`). Hope we cannot avoid that no?

Comment: Yes it'd have to be named differently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)?  That seems to be more in line with what you're asking for than your currently accepted answer:

```
// import from module
import { LibraryItem } from 'librarymodule'; 

// locally augment the module's interface declaration  
declare module './playground' {
  export interface LibraryItem {
    isPhotoSelected: boolean
  }
}

// use it
const libtaryItem: LibraryItem = {
  id: 'id',
  photoURL: 'https://example.com/photo.jpg',
  fileName: 'fileName.ext',
  thumbnailURL: 'https://example.com/thumbnail.jpg',
  isPhotoSelected: true
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!